# roscd: command not found

Tags: ros, roscd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I faced this error: "roscd: command not found" same as rosnode except for roscore.

I have already setup my .bashrc by "source /opt/ros/jade/setup.bash"

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222260/roscd:-command-not-found/) by [Reza1984](https://answers.ros.org/users/8496/reza1984/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2015-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you check these?;

http://answers.ros.org/question/195052/command-not-found-roscd-rosnode-etc/
http://answers.ros.org/question/66913/roscd-command-not-found-in-groovy-1204/

Also you can check your environment variables.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Reza1984](https://answers.ros.org/users/8496/reza1984/) on 2015-12-10**:
Yes I have checked all the possible solutions in the net but none of them worked.

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2015-12-10**:
Can you check `printenv | grep ROS` output?

**Comment by [Reza1984](https://answers.ros.org/users/8496/reza1984/) on 2016-03-03**:
Sorry for late reply. I have installed ROS again and it works now.

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2016-03-03**:
Glad you solved it.